# Git update fails

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I'm currently trying to finish off a project at school and recently made a Git-Website for it. Currently I am trying to implement some other stuff but it seems like the gh-pages branch is hindering me from that.

When I try to update or commit anything i get the following error:

> "No tracked branch configured for branch gh-pages.
>   To make your branch take a remote branch call, for example,
>   git branch --set-upstream gh-pages origin/gh-pages"

I know there is a thread about this already but all the responses people gave there didn't fix it for me, so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: have you ever pushed your local `gh-pages` branch to any remote ? If yes, can you please post the command and tell me whether it was successful or not?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you don't have a remote branch tracking the local branch.

Just type `git branch --set-upstream gh-pages origin/gh-pages` in terminal, it'll create remote branch and associate it with your local branch.

The other option is `git push -u origin gh-pages`

Comment: i get the error: 

The --set-upstream flag is deprecated and will be removed. Consider using --track or --set-upstream-to
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/gh-pages' does not exist
hint:
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint:
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.

using the first command

Comment: and i get the error: error: src refspec gh-pages does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'

with the second one

Comment: It means that you don't have local master branch. Try: `git checkout -b master`. Than you can push.